# Что такое оптимизация? Как оптимизировать код? Как оптимизировать программу?

Tags: оптимизация, теория

Огромное количество вопросов на SO про оптимизацию (кстати часто не указано по какому параметру :(). Расскажите общепринятые практики по оптимизации, литературу и методы, которые можно и нужно использовать.

В текущем вопросе необходимо рассказать о тех методах, которые работают и их эффективность видна в общем случае. Не нужно рассказывать о том, что помогло конкретно вам в вашей узкой задаче - только общие методики, желательно с ссылками на литературу или другие авторитетные источники.

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Господа минусующие, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с хинтом к кнопке минуса - этот вопрос вполне отражает стремление разобраться, он понятен, и несет пользу.

Comment: @Kromster, от этого он не становится менее широким. Плюс непонятно - это все-таки список литературы хотят или множество каких-то ответов по всем возможным темам?

Comment: @Grundy голоса и тревоги - это ортогональные категории. Если считаете необходимым закрывать как широкий - пожалуйста =). В вопросе уточнено, что нужны общие методики, по возможности(!), со ссылками на литературу. Мне кажется этот вопрос (и ответ) могли бы быть общими и каноничным для большого количества случаев. Вижу в них однозначную пользу для ruSO.

Comment: Общая методика оптимизации кода — это "замерить, внести изменения, замерить еще раз, если есть статистически значимое улучшение — задеплоить на прод".

Comment: Суть этого вопроса разъяснить общие случаи при оптимизации по разным параметрам, т.к. таких вопросов довольно много и молодые ребята даже не знают как к такой задаче подойти и с чего начать.Более того, многие вообще не понимают что это , как это и почему это.@Nofate , вы же это описали в 2 словах, а получали этот опыт несколько лет, это не очевидно,когда человек впервые столкнулся с этим. Вот в этом вопросе мы можем передать опыт и направить на путь решения проблемы. Эти решения будут пригодны для большого кол-ва вопросов, связанных с оптимизацией

Comment: Просьбы о переоткрытии к вопросу отношения не имеют и им в нем не место. Сделал откат

Comment: ПРОСЬБА, ЕСЛИ ВАМ ПОМОГ ЭТОТ ВОПРОС И ОТВЕТЫ, ПРОГОЛОСУЙТЕ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ЗА ПЕРЕОТКРЫТИЕ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Задал вопрос я - я и начну
Первое, что вам необходимо понимать при использовании термина оптимизация это то, что оптимизированным можно быть только по какому-то параметру: по скорости работы программы, по памяти, по объему исходного кода, по времени разработки кода и т. п. Поэтому всегда указывайте параметр (критерий) оптимальности.

Кстати, если вы новичок и вам кажется, что вы сейчас будете писать только оптимальный чистый код и хорошие программы, то вам следует задуматься,если вы хотите работать программистом. Хорошая программа - та, которая удовлетворяет условиям Технического Задания (то есть работает так, как написано заказчиком, даже если заказчик это вы сам или ваша же компания), а не та в которой использованы самые новые алгоритмы и инструменты.Если в большой сложной системе, где всплывает список выбора чисел от 1 до 10 и вы отсортируете числа пузырьком, а не квиксортом - ничего не изменится. Поэтому вы должны понимать, что первый приоритет - программа по ТЗ, а потом если у вас есть лишнее время или для собственного интереса (или заказчик требует ускорить новыми правками в ТЗ) вы можете туда накручивать любые оптимизации по любому параметру. Скажу ещё один фактор хорошего кода - читаемость и понятность,только так вы сможете поддерживать свою программу в долгосрок (само собой это для коммерческой разработки, а не для олимпиадных задач), рекомендую делать код прежде всего читаемым, а уже потом всё остальное. Читаемость кода - залог конкурентоспособности вашей программы.

Не лишним будет напомнить, что ваш компилятор часто сам несколько оптимизирует работу программы (часто при сборке надо указать, что это релиз, а не дебаг. Почитайте про вашу версию компилятора и его параметры). Поэтому к ручной оптимизации вам стоит прибегать только когда все автоматизированные решения уже использованы.

**Чаще всего всплывают вопросы про оптимизацию по скорости, поэтому о ней и расскажу.**

1. Прежде чем оптимизировать рабочую программу по скорости, вы должны её получить. Преждевременная оптимизация может отнять у вас много сил и времени впустую, а может и запутает разработку вовсе, поэтому сначала напишите прогу хоть как-то.
2. Далее следует определить узкие места программы — это доступно программисту любого уровня. Ставьте таймеры на входе в функцию, выводите результат на выходе. Посмотрите какая функция в программе используется дольше всего (в том числе и суммарно). Можете использовать специальные программы — профайлеры, они анализируют и помогают собрать статистику, я обычно пользуюсь логгированием программы.
3. Следующим шагом вы должны оценить и принять решение - в каком месте вы будете оптимизировать. Если ваша программа работает 100 секунд,а в самом начале есть функция которая работает целых 5 секунд, но вызывается всего 1 раз и есть функция, которая вызывается n раз, но работает 1,5 секунды за раз, вам следует сделать выбор первого приоритета в пользу последней функции, т. к. она вызывается n раз и при масштабировании вашей программы может вызываться ещё чаще.
   Также на этом шаге вы должны понимать почему то или иное место работает 8 секунд, а не 3.Причины могут быть не только внутренние, на которые вы можете повлиять, но и внешние (например обращение по API или взаимодействие с СУБД), внешние причины стоит рассмотреть особенно внимательно т.к. условия их работы могут меняться и сегодня БД может дать ответ за 1 секунду, а завтра за 5, а вы будете считать, что новые 4 секунды — вина вашего кода.Более того, думаю, все понимают, что ускорить места, зависимые от внешних причин — сложно, т. к. нужно будет отделять внутреннюю и внешнюю часть и ускорять только внутреннюю, но и даже так, внутренняя не сможет начать свою работу до тех пор, пока не отработает внешняя из-за зависимости.
4. Расставив приоритеты оптимизации, оцените возможности для каждого места, где вы собрались ускорять работу.
   Решения принимайте с таким приоритетом:
   **а)** Алгоритмическая оптимизация - зачастую самая полезная и эффективная. Чаще всего её достаточно. Рассмотрите другие алгоритмы работы для вашего узкого места программы
   **a+)** Вероятно(НЕ ВСЕГДА!!!) работе вашей функции поможет кеширование и вы можете хранить хотя-бы часть результатов(всегда или определённое время). Это действительно может существенно помочь вам.
   **б)** Особенности инструментов - заглуглите как ускорить именно ваши инструменты (яркий пример постфикс и префикс в с++, хотя уже несколько лет в g++ при релизе разницы почти никакой).
   **в)** Чистка костылей, удаление лишних команд, выбор других типов данных, уменьшение отладочных выводов и логов и тп. Это последнее т.к. даст самый незначительный эффект.

Успехов!

Comment: Господа минусующие, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с хинтом к кнопке минуса - этот ответ очень даже полезен.

Answer (score 7):

Оптимизировать можно на нескольких уровнях. Первое - конечно же **читаемость кода**, особенно если код вы пишете в компании. Лучше придерживаться общепринятых принципов написания кода, например как тут: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions, или вот в этом руководстве по именованию переменных: https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/articles/variables

Теперь наш код чистый. Что дальше? Дальше следует **поправить архитектуру** (а лучше сразу правильно писать, ибо потом будет сложнее рефакторить весь проект в принципе). Тут лучше придерживаться определенных принципов (https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/426413/), или например паттернов. Подробнее про выбор правильного паттерна конкретно под каждый проект можно почитать тут: https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/325492/, тут: https://gb.ru/blog/patterny-proektirovaniya/ и тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/276593/

Теперь у нас нормальная архитектура, у нас чистый код, но вот незадача: наш проект работает очень медленно. Что делать? **Оптимизировать производительность**. Возьмём пример с С#, где это можно сделать в нескольких местах: в асинхронности (https://habr.com/ru/post/458332/, https://habr.com/ru/post/452094/), в запросах к бд (как описано тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/489226/. Статья про LINQ), и в отправках HTTP запросов (https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/583434/). Можно перейти на хардкорный low-level, но только в тех случаях, когда вы точно уверены, что это необходимо.

Как правильно заметили в комментариях, не хватает пункта про **оптимизацию алгоритмов**. А это важно (кейс есть в этой статье: https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/655927/), потому что выбор алгоритма (особенно при высокой нагрузке) может как навредить производительности, так и способствовать ускорению программы. Как правило, эффективность алгоритма измеряется с помощью Big O notation (https://habr.com/ru/post/444594/), и главное - выбрать правильный алгоритм. Список основных есть вот тут: https://proglib.io/p/required-programmer-algorithms, визуализация алгоритмов есть вот тут: https://thimbleby.gitlab.io/algorithm-wiki-site/, визуализация структур данных тут: [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/Algorithms.html)

Хорошо, мы все классно ускорили, наоптимизировали, украсили... Но зачем? Затем, что теперь код вашего проекта:

1. Легче читать
2. Легче внедрять в него фичи, изменять уже существующие
3. Он быстрый

Надеюсь, ответил на ваш вопрос, удачи в проектах ! :)