# Помогите оптимизировать код и, мб, подкорректировать, пожалуйста

Tags: python, оптимизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
num_of_students = int(input())
a = 1
if num_of_students <= 4:
        print(0)
elif num_of_students == 5:
        print(1)
else:
        for i in range(5, num_of_students):
                a += 1

        print(a)
```

Comment: Можете ознакомиться - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас прочту

Comment: Здравствуйте, по какому параметру вы хотите оптимизировать?

Comment: ЧТО оптимизировать??? Где хоть как-то работающее решение?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Добрый день, по времени выполнения. В некоторых тестах с неизвестными значениями выдает time limit exceeded.

Comment: @MBo мое решение работает, но да, далеко не на всех значениях, а на большей части выдает ошибку с time limit. Извините, я только учусь.

Answer (score 0):

Приведённое решение неверное.

Останутся на месте студенты с номерами

```
1 + k*20
2 + k*20
3 + k*20
4 + k*20
```

где k -целое число, а `20 = НОК(4,5)`
Таким образом, нужно посчитать количество таких студентов, и отнять от общего количества. Справитесь?

В каждой двадцатке четыре остаются на месте. Значит, можно найти количество оставшихся, разделив целочисленно (n-1) на 20 и умножив результат на 4. При этом не учли последнюю двадцатку, в которую может входить от 0 до 4 человек - для этого нужно проверить остаток от деления (n-1)%20

Comment: Гигантское вам спасибо, попробую перевести в код. Хорошего вам дня! Хотя, честно, выглядит сложновато.

Comment: Уточню только на всякий случай, что задача потребует вычисления по нескольким формулам, а не перебора и проверки всех точек

Comment: извините, никак не получается, не могли бы вы решить, пожалуйста? В любом случае, я буду ее разбирать.

Comment: извините, у меня совсем не получается, можете, пожалуйста, решить ее?