# Оптимизация задачи на python

Tags: python, оптимизация, числа-фибоначчи

Задача с кодварса 5 кю python . https://www.codewars.com/kata/5541f58a944b85ce6d00006a
Набросал такой код, тесты проходит но как я понял выходит из строя на тестах с большими числами(Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)).

```
def Fibonachi(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    if n > 2:
        return Fibonachi(n - 2) + Fibonachi(n - 1)
def productFib(prod):
    n = 1
    while Fibonachi(n) * Fibonachi(n+1) < prod:
        n += 1
        if prod == Fibonachi(n) * Fibonachi(n + 1):
            return [Fibonachi(n), Fibonachi(n + 1), True]
            break
    if Fibonachi(n) * Fibonachi(n+1) > prod:
        return [Fibonachi(n), Fibonachi(n+1), False]
```

Кому лень читать с сайта, тогда условия задачи вкратце

на вход дается число, если это число равняется какому-то n фибоначчи * n+1 фибоначчи нужно вывести

```
n фибоначи, n+1 фибоначи, True
```

в противном случае алгоритм такой:

```
productFib(800) # should return (34, 55, false),
# since F(8) = 21, F(9) = 34, F(10) = 55 and 21 * 34 < 800 < 34 * 55
```

Не совсем понимаю в чем ошибка и как можно  оптимизировать код, молю о помощи.

Comment: для вычисления чисел фибоначчи лучше использовать цикл, а не рекурсию. либо для рекурсии использовать декоратор `functools.lru_cache`

Comment: Ну это уже не смешно, десятки ответов  и других источников есть, как считать фибоначчи за нормальное время, а не этот изврат.

Comment: Благодарю,lru_cache помог

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас есть пара последовательных чисел Фибоначчи *(f<sub>n-1</sub>, f<sub>n</sub>)* следующая за ней пара вычисляется как *(f<sub>n</sub>, f<sub>n-1</sub> + f<sub>n</sub>)*. На Питоне получается особенно компактно:

```
def productFib(prod):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a * b < prod:
        a, b = b, a + b
    return [a, b, a * b == prod]
```

**P.S.** Это решение одно из самых популярных на codewars. Есть решение ещё быстрее, но *поля книги слишком узки для него*.