# Как улучшить код для решения арифметической задачи?

Tags: python-3.x, оптимизация, арифметика

Приложенный ниже код решает следующую задачу:

> Найдите наибольшее натуральное число, такое, что если прибавить к нему сумму его цифр, получится число, введённое пользователем.

```
# Найдите наибольшее натуральное число, такое, что если прибавить
# к нему сумму  его цифр, получится число, введённое пользователем.

n = int(input())
k = n
while (k + sum(int(digit) for digit in str(k)) != n) and k!=0:
    k -= 1
if k!=0:
    print(k)
else:
    print('No such positive integer.')
```

Приму любую конструктивную критику, направленную на оптимизацию вышеизложенного кода.

Comment: Надо научится за логарифм строить нужное число.

Comment: При работе с числами лучше избегать преобразования в строки и обратно - это не эффективно. К тому же задача **арифметическая**

Comment: Зачем вы завели новый аккаунт? Теперь два Дененберга.

Comment: Я пароль от старого забыл.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу небольшой пример как можно решить задачу за меньшее время, тест скорости включен.

**Основная идея**

- Для вычисления суммы пользуемся исключительно арифметикой.

Код

```
import time

def test(n):
    k = n
    while (k + sum(int(digit) for digit in str(k)) != n) and k!=0:
        k -= 1
    if k!=0:
        return(k)
    else:
        return('No such positive integer.') 

def findSum(num):
    s = 0
    while num > 0: 
        s += num % 10
        num = num // 10
    return s    

def test2(n):
    k = n
    while k and (k + findSum(k) != n):
        k -= 1
    if k:
        return(k)
    return('No such positive integer.') 

start = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    r = test(i)
end = time.time()
print(end - start, r)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    r = test2(i)
end = time.time()
print(end - start, r)
```

Вывод:

```
9.353121042251587 9972
4.550509214401245 9972
```

*В итоге мы получили почти двухкратную производительность.*

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @ЯнАльбертовичДененберг Пожалуйста! Посмотрите еще на всякий случай если не видели [Дзен Пайтона](https://pythonchik.ru/osnovy/dzen-python-pep20#zen-of-python-na-russkom-yazyke) — приучает к хорошему стилю

Answer (score 4):

Первая оптимизация которая приходит в голову - сумма цифр любого *k ≤ n* не превосходит *9·<количество цифр n>*. Другими словами, не надо отступать слишком далеко от *n*:

```
def k(n):
    for k in range(n, max(0, n - 9 * len(str(n)) - 1), -1):
        if k + sum(map(int, str(k))) == n:
            return k
    return None
```

Сложность старого варианта была *n·log n*. Первый множитель - число повторений цикла проверки, второй - стоимость одной проверки (*сложность занижена, но для наших целей сойдет*).

Новый вариант имеет сложность *log<sup>2</sup> n*. Число итераций сократилось в худшем случае с линейного до логарифма.

Квадрат с логарифма можно убрать, если понять что суммы цифр соседних целых различаются мало. Получится сложность *log n*, которая является оптимальной, так как логарифм требуется чтобы прочитать все цифры числа.

**P.S.** Про замену `str` делениями. В теории замена ухудшает сложность. Чтобы извлечь из числа *n* все цифры делением на десять требуется *log<sup>2</sup> n* операций - *log n* делений, каждое из которых тоже стоит *log n*. Функция `str` могла бы делать это быстрее - перевод между системами счисления можно сделать с лучшей сложностью...

**P.P.S.** ... но в Питоне `str` реализован медленно, за квадрат логарифма.

Comment: хорошие показатели!