# Суммы двух последовательных точных степеней

Tags: python-3.x, оптимизация, арифметика

В рамках одного из IQ-тестов предлагалось следующее задание:

> Продолжите последовательность: 5, 12, 17, 25, 41, 52, ?, ?

Вот неоптимизированный код, решающий эту задачу:

```
# Вычисляем суммы двух последовательных точных степеней,
# не превосходящих числа, введённого пользователем.

k=int(input())
d=0
while 2**(d+1)<=k:
    d+=1
list=[]
for pow in range (2, d+1):
    i=1
    while i**pow<=k:
        list.append(i**pow)
        i+=1
for i in range(len(list) - 1):
    list2=sorted(set(list))
for i in range(len(list2) - 1):
    print(list2[i] + list2[i + 1])
```

Как можно улучшить данный код?

Comment: Предпоследний цикл меня пугает.

Comment: Меня тоже. Увы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770