# Как оптимизовать код при MemoryError?

Tags: python, оптимизация

Есть такой код:

```
a = 565754545445
print([x for x in str(list(range(1, a + 1)))])
```

Если я попытаюсь его запустить, то получу:

```
>>> MemoryError
```

Знаю как исправить с помощью сторонних библиотек. Но есть ли вариант сделать это только с помощью базовых возможностей Python?

По большому счету, выводить весь этот лист не нужно. Нужно лишь узнать сколько раз в этом дипазоне встречается конкретная цифра, например 9. То есть вот так:

```
a = 100
print(len([i for i in str(list(range(1, a + 1))) if i == '9']))
```

Это работает для небольших чисел. Например, 100. Но хотелось бы понять, как сделать то же самое для огромных чисел.

Comment: Да. Спасибо за ссылку! Нашел там ответ. Почему-то не заметил, когда создавал вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно подсчитать количество девяток, тогда не нужно сохранять весь диапазон ненужных цифр в памяти. Можно брать по одной цифре и анализировать ее. После того как проанализировали выбрасывать и так до конца диапазона цифр.

```
def count_number(end_num):
    count = 0
    start_num = 1
    while start_num <= end_num:
        if '9' in str(start_num):
            count += 1;
        start_num += 1
        
    return count
    
print(count_number(100))
```