# Как оптимизировать построчный ввод данных?

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация, input, олимпиада

Подается число n (n = 173 528). Это кол-во слов, которые затем подаются построчно.

Пробовал использовать:

```
input = io.BytesIO(os.read(0, os.fstat(0).st_size)).readline
```

Еще пробовал тестировать с заранее известными данными и моя программа выдавала ответ менее чем за 2 секунды (то есть вся проблема заключается скорее всего в вводе большого кол-ва данных).

Как можно оптимизировать этот ввод? (Данные с ввода сразу записываю в массив)

Comment: Уберите одну из меток и вместо неё добавьте метку языка. Без неё ваш вопрос "невидим" для многих специалистов.

Comment: Нужно было хоть чуть-чуть больше кода показать. А ещё лучше - весь код. Много где может быть засада.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю что язык - Питон. Напечатаем файл из 200000 длинных целых чисел:

```
for n in range(10 ** 64, 10 ** 64 + 200000):
    print(n)
```

> ```
> $ python make-list.py > in.txt
>
> $ wc in.txt 
>   200000   200000 13200000 in.txt
> ```

200000 строк, 13Mb.

Теперь прочитаем этот файл медленно. Каждая строки читается отдельно внутри блока `try` и преобразуется в целое число:

```
c = 0
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input())
    except EOFError:
        break
    c += 1
print(c)
```

> ```
>  $ time python read-list.py < in.txt
> 200000
>
> real  0m0.321s
> user  0m0.280s
> sys   0m0.036s
> ```

За треть секунды всё прочитано, преобразовано и сосчитано. Ищите причины медлительности вашей программы в другом месте.

Ещё одна попытка. Читаем строки из итератора. Преобразование в целые всё ещё есть:

```
import sys

c = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    n = int(line)
    c += 1
print(c)
```

> ```
> $ time python read-list.py < in.txt
> 200000
>
> real  0m0.127s
> user  0m0.120s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Одна восьмая секунды.

Без преобразований:

```
import sys

c = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    c += 1
print(c)
```

> ```
> $ time py temp.py < in.txt
> 200000
>
> real  0m0.059s
> user  0m0.056s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Одна шестнадцатая секунды.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, скорее всего в моей программе какая-то проблема, надо будет попробовать оптимизировать