# Оптимизация математического выражения

Tags: математика, оптимизация

Я пишу небольшой проект который может находить производную от функции, но после нахождения производный остается много мусора. К примеру производная от `x ** 2`:

```
(((2.0 * (x ** (2.0 - 1.0))) * 1.0) + (((x ** 2.0) * ln(x)) * 0.0))
```

Я смог написать небольшой оптимизатор который убирает не нужное и вот что он выдает:

```
2 * x
```

но он работает только на простых примерах. Он не справляется даже с таким выражением:

```
x / x                                               # исходной выражение
(((1.0 / x) * 1.0) + (((-(x)) / (x ** 2.0)) * 1.0)) # производная без оптимизации
((1.0 / x) - (x / (x ** 2.0)))                      # с оптимизацией
```

такое, если постараться, можно оптимизировать. Но большие проблемы начинаются с выражениями где много одинаковых операций. к примеру:

```
x ** 10
(10.0 * (9.0 * (8.0 * (7.0 * (6.0 * (x ** 5.0))))))
# производная 5 степени
```

У меня такой вопрос какие существуют методы оптимизации математических выражение и где о них можно почитать?

Comment: SymPy - Simplification: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sympy/sympy_simplification.htm

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770

Comment: @SpaceResearcher как это связано с моим вопросом?

Comment: @Danis   вам как минимум необходимо узнать что такое оптимизация, чтобы больше не употреблять термины, значение которых вы не понимаете

Comment: @SpaceResearcher какой-же термин мне лучше использовать?