# Ускорить код, ищущий числа, у которых сумма делителей даёт остаток 3 при делении на само число

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, арифметика

Числа 4 и 18 обладают довольно занимательным свойством. Сумма делителей даёт остаток 3 при делении на само число.

Мои попытки найти хотя бы ещё одно число с этим свойством не увенчались успехом:

```
for n in range(1, 200000):
    divisors = [i for i in range(1, int(n**(0.5))+1) if n % i == 0]
    divisors = divisors + [n // i for i in divisors if n//i != i]
    if sum(divisors) % n == 3:
        print(n, end=", ")
```

То есть в диапазоне до 200000 таких чисел нет, а чтобы искать дальше, нужно оптимизировать слишком медленно работающий код.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-быстрому можно `Numba` припахать, это даёт небольшое продвижение, но новых чисел нет и дальше всё-равно затык по времени выполнения:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(m):
    for n in range(1, m):
        divisors = [i for i in range(1, int(n**(0.5))+1) if n % i == 0]
        divisors = divisors + [n // i for i in divisors if n//i != i]
        if sum(divisors) % n == 3:
            yield n
            
%time print(list(func(5_000_000)))
```

Вывод:

```
[4, 18]
CPU times: user 35.6 s, sys: 68.6 ms, total: 35.6 s
Wall time: 35.6 s
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!