# Есть готовый работающий код, но необходимо ускорить его выполнение. Код на python. Помогите, пожалуйста, это сделать?

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

Есть такой написанный мною код на python. Никакие библиотеки кроме стандартных использовать нельзя. Работает он верно, часть тестов проходит, но заваливает тесты со слишком большими входными данными, превышая лимит времени. Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно ускорить его выполнение?

```py
num_oder = int(input())
j = 0
list_result = []
order_list = []
while j < num_oder:
    line_order = input()
    line_order_list = line_order.split()
    order_list.append(line_order_list)
    j = j + 1
num_request = int(input())
k = 0
while k < num_request:
    cost_sum = 0
    duration_sum = 0
    line_request = input()
    line_request_list = line_request.split()
    start_req = int(line_request_list[0])
    end_req = int(line_request_list[1])
    type_req = int(line_request_list[2])
    if type_req == 1:
        for a in order_list:
            if start_req <= int(a[0]) <= end_req:
                cost_sum = cost_sum + int(a[2])
            else:
                cost_sum = cost_sum + 0
    else:
        for a in order_list:
            if start_req <= int(a[1]) <= end_req:
                duration = int(a[1]) - int(a[0])
                duration_sum = duration_sum + duration
            else:
                duration_sum = duration_sum + 0
    if type_req == 1:
        list_result.append(str(cost_sum))
    else:
        list_result.append(str(duration_sum))
    k = k + 1
print(" ".join(list_result))
```

*На вход подается:* число заказов, заказы (время начала в мин, время конца, стоимость), число запросов, запросы (время начала в мин, время конца, тип запроса). если тип запроса 1 - нужно найти стоимость заказов, которые начались в данный промежуток времени, если тип 2 - нужно найти продолжительность заказов, которые завершились в данный промежуток времени.
*В выводе:* значения в одну строку через пробел
**Пример входных данных:**
3
5 20 5
6 21 4
6 22 3
2
6 12 1
4 6 1

**Пример выходных данных:**
7 12

Comment: Решение одно - сменить алгоритм. На какой? Не спрашивайте - вы же тоже условие задачи не приводите :)

Comment: Привожу же, под кодом))

Comment: Что на входе. Обычно перед этим идет достаточно большое описание происходящего... Сильно вам понятно такое условие? 
"**Входные данные**

Программа читает сначала количество звеньев k, а далее - k чисел 0 или 1 (0 - серебряное звено, 1 - золотое). Все числа вводятся одной строкой через пробелы.

**Выходные данные**

Программа выводит единственное число - минимальное количество разрезов и номера звеньев, между которыми сделано разрезы. Первый разрез должен быть как можно ближе к началу цепи. N < 10000."

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы знаете что такое заметание?

Comment: Мелочь, конечно, но зачем вот эта ветка кода: `else: cost_sum = cost_sum + 0`, и эта тоже `else: duration_sum = duration_sum + 0`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468769/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4/1468770#1468770